# Set environment variables using ./ instead of eval

Tags: bash

I have a script `version.sh`:

`echo export VERSION="version-1.3"`

I use this in another bash script `test.sh`:

```
eval "$(version.sh)"
echo $VERSION
```

The above code works and prints the version correctly.

However, I do not want to use `eval`. Is there a way to set environment variables and use them outside of another bash script without using `eval`? For example, could I just use `./version.sh`?

Comment: You can (and should) use `source` instead of eval. But no, regular child processes cannot change the environment of their parent using documented/supported/standardized interfaces.

Comment: Remove `echo` from `version.sh`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy am I able to set environment variables in the child with `source`?

Comment: With `source` the script is run in the existing shell process, so there is no new parent/child relationship created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

version.sh:

```
export VERSION="version-1.3"
```

test.sh:

```
. version.sh
echo $VERSION
```

The dot in `. version.sh` is the same as the command `source version.sh`. What it does is it executes commands from the file in the current shell. It doesnt run a new shell as in `./version.sh`.

More info [here](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-source-command/)